# Google Apps Script to Microsoft SQL Server clarification of whitelist certain IP ranges in database settings

Tags: sql-server, google-apps-script

Clarification of Google instructions for setting up `Jdbc.getConnection` to Microsoft SQL Server it says:

> In order to create a database connection using the JDBC service you must whitelist certain IP ranges in your **database settings** to allow Apps Script to access it.

My database is on a server that also has other databases. I've looked all through the database settings of the database I created using (SQL Server Management Studio) where I built the database. I asked the database person they told me "the server is set to allow remote connections" and I can see in the database properties under Connections the checkbox is checked for *"Allow remote connections to this server"* - that does not seem to make a difference. When I run my code - it does not error and it does not connect - it tells me either my connection string or login/password is incorrect. I reviewed the instructions and googled that message and number of folks also mentioned seeing the same message and they said they had to add the list of whitelist IPs per the Google instructions.

These are the address ranges you'll need to whitelist:

```
64.18.0.0 - 64.18.15.255
64.233.160.0 - 64.233.191.255
66.102.0.0 - 66.102.15.255
66.249.80.0 - 66.249.95.255
72.14.192.0 - 72.14.255.255
74.125.0.0 - 74.125.255.255
173.194.0.0 - 173.194.255.255
207.126.144.0 - 207.126.159.255
209.85.128.0 - 209.85.255.255
216.239.32.0 - 216.239.63.255
```

I've looked at every single property in the database nothing says "IP" or "address" is this a permissions issue or something that is accessed from a menu I don't have access to?

Could you please share with me where this "database whitelist" is to be entered for the database?

When I find it, will I be able to whitelist (allow access) the list of IPs above without causing an issue to any other databases on the server? I'm not sure if a shared server would be different than a dedicated server.

Also, I have asked and the network people tell me these IPs are not being blocked, but the Google instructions specifically say **database settings**, so I suspect Google is expecting something pretty specific to be set up.

Lastly, when I remote desktop to the database server I am not able to locate any kind of "Administrative Tools" menu to search under that.

Thanks for bearing with all the "newbie" questions.

For reference this is working code per the solution below.

```
function myFunction() {

var address = 'IPaddress\\instance';
var user = 'UserName';
var userPwd = 'ItsASecret';
var queryDb = 'DatabaseName';
var dbUrl = 'jdbc:sqlserver://' + address + ':1433;databaseName=' + queryDb;

var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
var start = new Date();
var stmt = conn.createStatement();

stmt.setMaxRows(100);
var results = stmt.executeQuery("select * from dbo.tablename");

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheetTab = sheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var cell = sheetTab.getRange('A1');
var numCols = results.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
var numRows = sheetTab.getLastRow();
var headers ;
var row =0;

for(var i = 1; i <= numCols; i++){
  headers = results.getMetaData().getColumnName(i);
    cell.offset(row, i-1).setValue(headers);
    }

while (results.next()) {
  var rowString = '';
  for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
    rowString += results.getString(col + 1) + '\t';
    cell.offset(row +1, col).setValue(results.getString(col +1 ));
  }
  row++
  Logger.log(rowString)
}

results.close();
stmt.close();
conn.close();
}
```

Comment: Ask your database person for server logs. Then ping your database from apps script. See why the connection got rejected in the sql server logs.

Comment: Ran some tests one is website the other is the sql server. The website one (not the one I need) returns a 200 status code the other a DNS error - going back to network folks to ask. ` var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('something.xxxxx.zzz', { muteHttpExceptions: true, validateHttpsCertificates: false, followRedirects: true }); var siteStatus = response.getResponseCode(); Logger.log("status code: " + siteStatus);`

Comment: I've looked through the server logs - Under Management > SQL Server Logs I'm not seeing any log that matches the credentials used, or that log that looks "different" in some way to appear as an error message.

Comment: [Edit] your question to provide the code you're using to access the database.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out after getting a different network person involved the port was not active on the server - even though the settings in the server itself looked like the port was set up to be used.

```
var dbUrl = 'jdbc:sqlserver://' + address + ':1433;databaseName=' + queryDb;
```

This command (I ran it from a PowerShell command prompt) is very helpful for checking that detail out:

```
Test-NetConnection -Port 800 -ComputerName 1xx.1xx.0.1 -InformationLevel Detailed
```

I want to also point out in my situation. I did not have to whitelist anything. Once the network person set up the address to use for the external connection and the port issue was resolved - (the port also had to be set to dedicated) everything flowed right through.

Comment: Can you please explain more about that command Test-NetConnection?? where do I run it and what is does InformationLevel stand for?

Comment: I ran the Test-NetConnection command from a Powershell. I am not a network person, but I found out about this command by searching stackoverflow for "how to determine if a port is open on a windows server" - the post is still there and has a lot of good information about the details.